# Jquery To change according to browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width, browser-width

I want the Div tag to be empty if the browser width > 760 px and less than 980 px but it looks like i am doing something wrong

```
    (function($){

  //detect the width on page load
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var current_width = $(window).width();
     //do something with the width value here!
    if(current_width < 980 && current_width > 760){
       $('#chwd').empty();
    }
  });

  //update the width value when the browser is resized (useful for devices which switch from portrait to landscape)
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var current_width = $(window).width();
   //do something with the width value here!

    if(current_width < 980 && current_width > 760  ){
         $('#chwd').empty();
    }
    else{
        $('#chwd').html(

<div id="ahead">
<div class="column">
Cash On Delivery
</div>
</div>

        );}
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Any Help would be Appreciated

Thanx

Comment: Are you getting width correctly? And what is the result you get?

Comment: When you are saying empty, do you mean you want to delete the content? or simply hiding it?

Comment: @Anamika yes i am getting the width correctly but only if remove the else statement, it does not seem to work with else statement

Comment: @StephanusYanaputra:- empty in the way that the content of that div id becomes null or "" or nothing blank

Comment: Cool, don't forget to select the answer @angadarora , so the topic is marked correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is fine, the problem lies on how you construct the `$('#chwd').html()`

Javascript handles the new line differently. Unlike PHP or other language which allows you to continue putting new line as long it is wrapped with a quote / single quote. In Javascript everytime you do a new line, you will have to wrap it with '' and + (See my code)

**This is acceptable**

```
'Lorem' +
'Ipsum'
```

**This is not acceptable**

```
'Lorem
 Ipsum'
```

**Try this:**

```
 (function($){

  //detect the width on page load
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var current_width = $(window).width();
     //do something with the width value here!
    if(current_width < 980 && current_width > 760){
       $('#chwd').empty();
    }
  });

  //update the width value when the browser is resized (useful for devices which switch from portrait to landscape)
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var current_width = $(window).width();
   //do something with the width value here!

    if(current_width < 980 && current_width > 760  ){
         $('#chwd').empty();
    }
    else{
        $('#chwd').html('<div id="ahead">'+
'<div class="column">'+
'Cash On Delivery'+
'</div>'+
'</div>');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `outerWidth` instead of `width`, it includes padding and border. You also need to wrap the `div`'s in "" otherwise the `html()` will assume it's a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change you else to this:

```
else{
   $('#chwd').html('<div id="ahead"><div class="column">Cash On Delivery</div></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in else statement:

```
else
{
    var divString = '<div id="ahead"><div class="column">'+
                    'Cash On Delivery'+
                    '</div></div>';
    $('#chwd').html(divString);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw, it was just hilarious :)